# Failed to execute goal while running maven build

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

My code was working fine, but suddenly when I tried to run the project as maven build, this error came up :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) on
>   project unicode: Could not start Tomcat: Failed to start component
>   [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed during start ->
>   [Help 1]

I tried a couple of solutions where I changed the installed jre to jdk, but it did not work.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ticketing.system</groupId>
  <artifactId>unicode</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hello, do let me know if you require more code to help me with a solution, I am very new to maven and servlets and need to submit the project tomorrow, any help with this error would be great. TIA

Comment: Add -X and -e when you execute maven goal to see more details on the error.

Comment: Should i write in the goal "-X and -e" ?

Comment: Should be something like "-X -e <your goal>" (no need to add double quote)

Comment: unable to figure out the error yet

Comment: Can you see more details? Please post additional message if yes.

Comment: @samabcde , I deleted the entire project and copy pasted the files in a new one. It worked fine. Thanks for your prompt responses.